# HTMLWorker.parse() incorrect html code

Tags: c#, html, winforms, itext, system.net.webexception

The program I make is supposed to convert Html to pdf with iTextsharp. but everytime i run the program, there is a error with the  `HTMLWorker.parse(stringreader reader);`. The exception says that it cannot find the network path.

```
    public string Run(string html, string pdfName)
    {
        try
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            //PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"L:\" + "Test54" + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
            string filePath = @"Z:\Emon Stage\" + "test" + ".pdf";
            using (FileStream pdfStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, pdfStream))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    doc.Open();
                    doc.OpenDocument();
                    doc.NewPage();
                    if (doc.IsOpen() == true)
                    {
                        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(html))
                        {
                            //XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, reader);
                            doc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
                            using (HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(doc))
                            {
                                worker.Open();
                                worker.StartDocument();
                                worker.NewPage();
                                worker.Parse(reader);
                                worker.SetStyleSheet(styles);

                                List<IElement> ie = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(reader, null);

                                foreach (IElement element in ie)
                                {
                                    doc.Add((IElement)element);
                                }

                                worker.EndDocument();
                                worker.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }

            doc.CloseDocument();
            doc.Close();
            doc.Dispose(); 

            return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

According to someone here at stackoverflow there is a problem with the html string i use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>
    AutoScout24: Fahrzeugdaten ausdrucken
</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="author" content="AutoScout24" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" /><meta name="description" content="Preis: 7.700 €, Baujahr: 1996, Leistung: 207 Kw (281 PS), Laufleistung: 169.000 km, Getriebe: Automatik, Kraftstoff: Benzin" /><meta name="keywords" content="AutoScout24" /><meta name="page-topic" content="AutoScout24" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="AutoScout24-Magazin RSS-Feed" href="http://ww2.autoscout24.de/magazine_rss.xml" /><script type="text/javascript" src="//s.autoscout24.net/combine/js?921b9c37a2e4ab133b1f14b8e13c02f073e017fd0bef1432f7d27433f4e9d289"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//s.autoscout24.net/cmsbox/99/2462008437" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//s.autoscout24.net/combine/css?69a1274c6bb2e43c6fd649686b1910dcb88846da731f33577731763848fed5ef8e57233cfa31bdac608a787bc54dc3dc25b21bb0e21eec631ca1c316e050af2aee3a9b1a4cd63f84d9ece894f4eceaaf85a689c0c1177a62cb374a776b2fdc53" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//s.autoscout24.net/combine/css?ef372438e68b2221" media="print" /><script type="text/javascript">$.as24={toggles:{'MyAreaB2BRedesignExport':1,'MyAreaInsertionITToggle':1,'MyAreaInsertionNLToggle':1,'RemoveStaticRoutes':1,'TestUsageRestServiceMessageTellAFriend':1,'LinkToWPOnDetailsPageDE':1,'SEOPageES':1,'NuggadATPixelToggle':1,'ProlongArticleInTwoSteps':1,'ArticleDeletionSurvey':1,'SealDataOnPrintOut':1,'AdvancedSearchTopArticlesRelocate':1,'CustomerExportJson':1}};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//s.autoscout24.net/combine/js?70f8f19d6b1d1f718cd532e95f5d6b2bb41768327b71a504f9edb406e60007f0c5c46b74b1e9cc69872734b354a85ce1e0adbfe55e4efc75"></script><meta name="title" content="Corvette C4 - AutoScout24" /><link rel="image_src" href="http://pic3.autoscout24.net/images-small/305/233/0219233305001.jpg?70cec1b69010c9baa7b920ce66f714ff" />
<!-- Start Visual Website Optimizer Asynchronous Code -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var _vwo_code=(function(){
var account_id=10842,
settings_tolerance=2000,
library_tolerance=1500,
use_existing_jquery=false,
// DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
f=false,d=document;return{use_existing_jquery:function(){return use_existing_jquery;},library_tolerance:function(){return library_tolerance;},finish:function(){if(!f){f=true;var a=d.getElementById('_vis_opt_path_hides');if(a)a.parentNode.removeChild(a);}},finished:function(){return f;},load:function(a){var b=d.createElement('script');b.src=a;b.type='text/javascript';b.innerText;b.onerror=function(){_vwo_code.finish();};d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);},init:function(){settings_timer=setTimeout('_vwo_code.finish()',settings_tolerance);this.load('//dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/j.php?a='+account_id+'&u='+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+'&r='+Math.random());var a=d.createElement('style'),b='body{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important;background:none !important;}',h=d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];a.setAttribute('id','_vis_opt_path_hides');a.setAttribute('type','text/css');if(a.styleSheet)a.styleSheet.cssText=b;else a.appendChild(d.createTextNode(b));h.appendChild(a);return settings_timer;}};}());_vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();
</script>
<!-- End Visual Website Optimizer Asynchronous Code -->
</head>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <body class="ie7">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->  
    <body>
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <div id="docu"><img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDetailImages_bigImage" src="http://pic2.autoscout24.net/images/305/233/0219233305001.jpg?70cec1b69010c9baa7b920ce66f714ff" alt="" border="0" />
    <br/><img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDetailImages_smallImageRepeater_ctl00_smallImage" src="http://pic4.autoscout24.net/thumbnails-big/305/233/0219233305002.jpg?22b74f6292d681883fe242fc9f719a2a" alt="" border="0" /><img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDetailImages_smallImageRepeater_ctl01_smallImage" src="http://pic4.autoscout24.net/thumbnails-big/305/233/0219233305003.jpg?27d71f459ce81983a794639f51f4e37f" alt="" border="0" /><img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDetailImages_smallImageRepeater_ctl02_smallImage" src="http://pic4.autoscout24.net/thumbnails-big/305/233/0219233305004.jpg?780b74044093e5c80f68f23ea84db5c2" alt="" border="0" /><img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDetailImages_smallImageRepeater_ctl03_smallImage" src="http://pic4.autoscout24.net/thumbnails-big/305/233/0219233305005.jpg?658b15994c9680a056140d2510783137" alt="" border="0" />
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>




<div id="globalLayerMask" class="globalLayerMask"></div>
<div id="globalLayer">
    <form id="layerForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    </form>
</div>

        <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="PrintViewArticles.aspx?id=219233305" id="aspnetForm">
<input type="hidden" name="contactSource" id="contactSource" value="Form" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />


<script type="text/javascript">
var cval=getCookieValue('as24Visitor',null);
setCookieValue('as24Visitor',cval===null?'a5f12924-6fad-495f-b551-fde651c9e4dc':cval,true);
</script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var firstIvwImage = new Image();
            function sendIvwReport()
            {
                firstIvwImage.src = "http://toi.ivwbox.de/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/07020801;/Autoscout24/Gebrauchtwagen-Suche.html?r=" + escape(document.referrer) + "&d=" + Date.parse(new Date());
            }
        sendIvwReport();
</script>   
            <div class="container">


  <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_omniturePixel" class="pixel">

<script type="text/javascript">
var s_account='autoscout24de';var s_pagename='Search-UC-Detail-Print';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s.autoscout24.net/combine/js?b52b5d64cd0410a8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try{s.dc=112;s.trackingServer="";s.trackingServerSecure="";s.server="www.autoscout24.de";s.pageName=s_pagename;s.channel="Search-UC";s.prop9="de-DE";s.prop1="16380";s.prop2="";s.prop11="";s.prop12="";s.prop13="";s.prop15="";s.prop16="";s.prop17="";s.prop18="";s.prop19="";s.prop20="";s.prop21="U";s.prop22="";s.prop25="";s.prop26="";s.prop27="";s.prop30="";s.prop42="";s.prop36="";s.prop4="Standard";s.prop29="S";s.eVar13="de-DE";s.eVar40="";s.eVar2="";s.eVar3="U";s.eVar4="";s.eVar5="";s.eVar6="";s.eVar8="";s.eVar9="";s.eVar14="";s.eVar15="";s.eVar17="";s.eVar18="";s.eVar31="";s.eVar49="";s.eVar58="";s.eVar12="";s.eVar23="P";s.eVar34="";s.eVar19="P";s.eVar20="S";s.eVar10="Standard";s.hier1="/16380";s.events="event7";s.products=";16380|19712|1996|B|P|2|8000"; var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code); } catch(e) {} finally {}
</script>

</div>
  <div class="info-top-area">


<div class="print-button-container">
  <div class="orange-rounded-button">
    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articlePrintHeader_printButton1" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="primary-action">
    <span class="l"></span><span class="m">Jetzt drucken</span><span class="r"></span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clear-both"></div>
<div class="print-header">
  <div class="print-logo">
      <img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articlePrintHeader_as24PrintLogo" src="//s.autoscout24.net/Images/_cache/ad95aba9b57bb3e9.jpg" alt="" border="0" />
  </div>
    <div class="date-insertion">
      <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articlePrintHeader_printFound">Inserat entdeckt am 03.09.2012</span>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>
  <div class="clear-both"></div>


<div class="print-dealer">

    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_customerInfo_privateCustomerInfo_contactAddressPanel" class="contact-address">

    <p>D&nbsp;97225 Zellingen</p>

</div>

<div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_customerInfo_privateCustomerInfo_contactPhonePanel" class="contact-phone no-margin">

    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_customerInfo_privateCustomerInfo_contactPhoneNoPanel">


                <p><b id="ctl00_decoratedArea_customerInfo_privateCustomerInfo_contactPhoneNoRepeater_ctl00_contactPhoneNoType">Tel.:</b>
                +49 (0)177 / 7931437</p>


    </div>

</div>

</div>
  <div class="clear-both"></div>
  <div class="left-content-area">
        <div class="detail-inner">


<div class="caption-box">
    <div class="article-caption">
        <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articleCaption_lblHead" class="detail-head">
    Corvette C4 
</div>        
        <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articleCaption_lblSubHeadDown" class="detail-subhead">

</div>
    </div>
</div>

        </div>
        <div class="detail-inner">
        <div class="floatLeft">
            <div class="detail-column-left">
                <div class="car-big">
    <div class="carpics">
        </div>
</div>
             </div>

             <div class="detail-column-right">


<div class="detail-info">
    <table class="i-detail">

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_pricePublicRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <b id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_pricePublicLabel">Preis:</b>

            </td>
    <td valign="bottom" class="price-fat">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_pricePublicValue">€ 7.700,-</span>
            </td>
</tr>





        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_emptyRow">
    <td colspan="2" style="height:13px"></td>
</tr>



        <tr>
            <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_offerTypeKey">Fahrzeugkategorie:</span>

            </td>
            <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_offerTypeValue">Gebraucht</span>
            </td>
        </tr>




        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_bodyTypeRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_bodyTypeKey">Aufbau:</span>
            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_bodyTypeValue">Cabrio</span>    
            </td>
</tr>

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_firstRegRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_firstRegKey">Erstzulassung:</span>
            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_firstRegValue">07/1996</span>
            </td>
</tr>

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_mileageRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_mileageKey">Kilometerstand:</span>
            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_mileageValue">169.000 km</span>
            </td>
</tr>

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_fuelRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_fuelKey">Kraftstoff:</span>

            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_fuelValue">Benzin</span>


            </td>
</tr>

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_powerRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_powerKey">Leistung:</span>
            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                    207
                    <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_kwUnit">kW</span>
                    (281
                    <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_hpUnit">PS</span>)
            </td>
</tr>

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_gearingTypeRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_gearingTypeKey">Getriebeart:</span>    
            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_gearingTypeValue">Automatik</span>
            </td>
</tr>

        <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_bodyColorRow">
    <td class="c1">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_bodyColorKey">Außenfarbe:</span>
            </td>
    <td class="c2">
                <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleDataControl1_bodyColorValue">Grün Metallic</span>
            </td>
</tr>









    </table>
</div>

            </div>
        </div>

             <div class="detail-column-left">   
                <div id="articleDetailEnvkv" class="envkv_box">





                </div>






             </div>


            <div class="detail-column-right">


<div class="dashed-line" style="margin-left:3px;"></div>
<div class="lower-right1">
    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleEquipments_equipmentsHead" class="actions-box-caption">
    Fahrzeugausstattung:
</div>
    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_myArticleEquipments_equipmentList" class="equi-list-all">
    Nichtraucherfahrzeug
</div>
</div>
                <div class="clear-both"></div>


<div class="dashed-line">
</div>
<div class="lower-right3">
    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticleMoreDetailsData_detailsCaption" class="actions-box-caption">
    Weitere Details zum Fahrzeug:
</div>
    <div class="more-details">
        <table class="i-detail" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticleMoreDetailsData_fuelRow" valign="top">
    <td class="c1">
                    <span>Alle Kraftstoffe:</Span>

                </td>
    <td class="c2">
                    <span class="c2-sub">Benzin</div>

                </td>
</tr>









            <tr id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticleMoreDetailsData_generalInspectionRow">
    <td class="c1">
                    <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticleMoreDetailsData_generalInspectionKeyLabel">HU/AU:</span>
                </td>
    <td class="c2">
                    <span id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticleMoreDetailsData_generalInspectionValueLabel">02/2014</span>
                </td>
</tr>


















        </table>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="dashed-line"></div>
<div class="sep-short">
    <img id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticlePrintFinancingData_seperatorImage3" src="//s.autoscout24.net/Images/_cache/275a32375231b176.gif" alt="" border="0" />
</div>
<div class="lower-right3">
    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticlePrintFinancingData_printFinancingHeader" class="actions-box-caption">
    Finanzdienstleistungen:
</div>


    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_ArticlePrintFinancingData_printFinancingDisclaimer" class="description-text">
    Bitte wenden Sie sich für ein individuelles Finanzierungs-, Leasing- oder Versicherungs-Angebot an Ihren  Partner.
</div>

</div>


                <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_AdServerArticleDetailItem" class="adbox">

</div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="clear-both"></div>
        <div class="lower-content-bottom"></div>


<div class="footer-warranty">
  <p id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articlePrintFooter_as24Warranty_disclaimerText" class="notice">AutoScout24 GmbH übernimmt für die Richtigkeit der Angaben keine Gewähr.</p>

</div>

<div class="print-button-container">
  <div class="orange-rounded-button">
    <div id="ctl00_decoratedArea_articlePrintFooter_printButton2" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="primary-action">
    <span class="l"></span><span class="m">Jetzt drucken</span><span class="r"></span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>  
    </div>
    <img src="http://tracking.autoscout24.com/parser.ashx?source=pr&amp;url=http://www.autoscout24.de/PrintViewArticles.aspx?id=219233305&amp;visitor=not_found&amp;ticks=634822815476118951" width="2" height="2" style="position: absolute" />

            </div>






<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    try {
    var resCookie=$.cookie('ResolutionParams');
    var domain=document.domain;
    if(domain.indexOf('.') > -1) domain=domain.substring(domain.indexOf('.'));
    if (!resCookie || true) {
        resCookie = screen.width.toString();
        $.cookie('ResolutionParams', resCookie, { expires: 365, domain: domain, path: '/'});
    }
} catch(e) {}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads.autoscout24.com/adserver/index4.aspx?slot=268&amp;language=ger&amp;site=1&amp;elementid=ctl00_decoratedArea_AdServerArticleDetailItem&amp;dealerid=12335432&amp;price=7700&amp;carfinancedby=0&amp;make=16380&amp;modell=19712&amp;strModell=C4&amp;strMake=Corvette&amp;vat=0&amp;body=2&amp;hsn=&amp;hp=281&amp;kw=207&amp;zip=97225&amp;age=194&amp;Year=1996&amp;carid=219233305&amp;adtype=P&amp;lastInspect=02/01/2014&amp;tsn=&amp;Mileage=169000&amp;carNo=&amp;cartype_id=C&amp;accident=U&amp;Month=7&amp;rnd=28&amp;ipaddress=1400240550&amp;ccm=0&amp;bildurl=http://pic2.autoscout24.net/images/305/233/0219233305001.jpg?70cec1b69010c9baa7b920ce66f714ff&amp;eurotaxid=0&amp;offertype=U&amp;fuel=B&amp;inter=&amp;cash=&amp;durat=&amp;rate=&amp;frate=&amp;tm=3"></script></form>

    <script src='//js.revsci.net/gateway/gw.js?csid=J11265&auto=t'></script>


<!-- m-pathy tracking [ start ] -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _mpathyHost = "http" + (document.location.protocol!="https:" ? "://m-pathy.gdlcdn.com/js/a" : "s://ne.wac.edgecastcdn.net/001262/m-pathy/js/as");
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + _mpathyHost + "2909.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<!-- m-pathy tracking [ end ] -->



        <span id="ctl00_VisualWebsiteOptimizer1"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have images with such path: `//s.autoscout24.net/Images/...`; probably the machine where you run the WinForms application does not have that network sharing. Add such sharing (same as on the web server) and it should work.

Comment: On second thought, I just noticed `http://s.autoscout24.net/Images/_cache/ad95aba9b57bb3e9.jpg` works just fine - so change the HTML if you can.

Comment: That's a lot of HTML, did the so user specify what he thought was wrong with the HTML string.  Second thing is that having used iTextSharp I have found that it has little to no error handling and often generates errors that have nothing to do with the actual problem.  Have you tried using the ITextShap source code and debugging through that to see where the real problem is.